# How to enable redis-search and redis-json on redis-stack docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I have a *docker-compose.yml* that I set up like this:

```
my-redis:
  image: redis/redis-stack
  networks:
    - base_network
  ports:
    - '6379:6379'
  command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --protected-mode no 
  volumes:
    - redis-data:/data
```

I need to use the RedisSearch and RedisJSON features from this image, but they are not activated by default and I couldn't find how to activate them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Redis Stack loads the modules automatically using multiple `--loadmodule /path/to/module.so` options when it calls `redis-server` on your behalf. So normally, you don't need to do anything.

However, as you are calling `redis-server` yourself by specifying the `command` option in *docker-compose.yml*, these options are not being provided. So, you'll need to provide them manually yourself.

Try this:

```bash
redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --protected-mode no \
  --loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisearch.so \
  --loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/rejson.so
```

Note that you'll probably need to remove the `\` that I added to get it to be readable. Not sure if YAML files allow that or not.

Also, for future reference, here are the paths to the all the modules inside Redis Stack.

| Module | Path |
| --- | --- |
| **RediSearch** | /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisearch.so |
| **RedisGraph** | /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisgraph.so |
| **RedisTimeSeries** | /opt/redis-stack/lib/redistimeseries.so |
| **RedisJSON** | /opt/redis-stack/lib/rejson.so |
| **RedisBloom** | /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisbloom.so |